# Rail3: Vendor Plugin accessing my server database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm current using the cartographer plugin, is it possible for the files in cartographer to access my user database and use its methods?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possible - but very unlikely.  Read the code if you're concerned.